# A word that signifies a “present-past perspective” and another for a “present-future perspective”?

Tags: single-word-requests

Conjugations help us distinguish temporal context as past, present or future, but they don't help us distinguish perspective from present to past or future, from past to present and future, or future to present and past.
I use hyphenations such as "from a present-to-past perspective," when deducing something given all I've learned up to the present.  And I use "from a present-to-future" perspective when I'm limiting my perspective of the future to my current limitations.  But are there any specific words that can accomplish this more fluidly for these types of perspectives?

**Present-to-past**: includes the benefit of all I have access to now, as opposed to the limitations I had then
**Past-to-present**: recognizes a perspective I used to have about what things would be like today
**Present-to-future**: is a perspective of the future limited to what I know now
**Future-to-present**: recognizes when I look back in the future to all that I've learned since now
**Past-to-future**: I can use words like 'lifetime,' 'atemporal' or 'the rest of my life.'

For example,

> "It can be difficult discussing things about our past with others if we don't include which perspective we're coming from, {present-to-past} or {past-to-present}."

I could write, "given what I know now," and "given what I knew then," but I'm looking for terminology that can be used more fluidly regarding all temporal perspectives, as opposed to just past, present and future.

Based on all of the comments thus far, it appears the words Retrospect, Perceive and Foresee are best for looking backwards, presently looking and future looking, respectively.  Each of them can be conjugated to cover every mental perspective; for example, "what I foresaw is far less mature than what I perceive today, and it will naturally be less mature than what I will retrospect in the future."  Here's a table that reflects all of that.

[image]

And if those words are best, then here are the abilities to do all of that which can be developed into valuable 'perspecting' skills: perceivable, foreseeable, prospectable and retrospectable?

Comment: Can you provide example sentences? Something like "from now on" or "henceforth" would express present-to-future.

Comment: From all **temporal** perspectives: past, present and future

Comment: @stuart F, I added another example and some alternatives at your suggestion.  As for the present-to-future, I'm referring more to mental perspectives, not physical ones.  I teach a concept I refer to as Perspeting (verb), which enables us to consciously change our perspective to add value in many ways, and I'm looking for any existing words that convey the perspectives I've already mentioned, not to mention a lot more....

Comment: @lambie, I recognize those 'existing' perspectives, but I'm referring to views of our past, present and future from another temporal existence.

Comment: I’m unclear exactly what you’re asking about. You mention conjugations, so morphological inflections of tense such as the verb *eat* for the 3rd person becoming *he ate* in the past and *he eats* in the non-past. But the rest of your post seems to be about things like aspect (eg: perfect-vs-imperfect) or mood (eg: indicative-vs-subjunctive) than it does tense (eg: past-vs-nonpast). I’m reminded of things like the Ancient Greek [aorists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aorist_(Ancient_Greek)) and [optatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optative_(Ancient_Greek)).

Comment: hindsight, reflection, foresight, prediction…synonyms thereof.

Comment: @tchrist if there was a way to conjugate it that would be great!  But it would also be a mountain too high to climb, and most people simply don't think that way very often.  So I mentioned that to differentiate conjugation from perhaps morphs added to the word 'perspective,' or words that mean "given what I know now" or "given what I knew then."  Also, it is definitely not mood, but it is a mental vantage point from one point in time to another point in time given what each brain was, is, or will be programmed.

Comment: @hipposawrus Hindsight works for "from what I know now about the past!"  Foresight works for "from what I believe about the future based on what I know now!)  Thank you!  The root word 'sight' is very helpful, though 'insight' would be more accurate.  Perspicaciously comes to mind given your inspiration, and I think I'll break that word down to see if I can discover even more of what I'm looking for--thanks again!

Comment: **prospective** would be looking futureward from the present, and **retrospective** would be looking backward at the past from the present.

Comment: I think the best bet is either to be explicit ("looking back from the present" etc), or if absolutely necessary, to invent a series of terms and define them. It's better to be clear and explicit even if it's slightly longer. Relying on tenses or particular uses of words with multiple meanings isn't ideal. You could also look on Writing SE because they have a lot of questions about time (some relating to time travel but not all).

Comment: Is this not one of too many 'single word' requests with no real use?

You seem to seek the shortening of three words into one… which would be useful, how? 

How could anyone meaningfully reduce 'present-past perspective' or 'present-future perspective' to fewer words?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin How? in counseling, we often wrestle with temporal perspectives, and simpler clarity can make discussing them more fluid and less awkward or efficient.  For example, if you are upset right now about something that happened in the past, are you thinking about it as though you were there once again (perceiving in that past while you are in the present), or are you thinking about it happening again at this moment (perceiving in the present based on something that happened in the past)...or concerned about the future repeating itself, yet another perspective.

Comment: Can you run that through again? 'simpler clarity', please?

'More fluid and less awkward or efficient'? How could that work? '… less awkward and less efficient'? '… less awkward but more efficient'? Please…

More, perhaps…

Comment: From any position or frame of reference, how could it be needful to point out that you must be referring purely to mental perspectives, not the clearly impossible 'physical ones'?

Comment: What could terms like 'from a present-to-past perspective' ever add to the more clear and simple 'looking back'?

Comment: I'm sorry to point out that to me, what any counsellor wrestles with should require at least a first if not a second degree and sometimes a doctorate. Who thinks that unreasonable, please say so now!

Meanwhile the Question and all its exposition seem to come from a high-school perspective… if perhaps, senior high.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin when I say "we," I mean helping the people we counsel distinguish between those mental perspectives.  Too often, people conflate how they feel right now about the past or future with what they felt about either one of them in the past, or might feel about them in the future.  Physical existence is simply past, present and future (high school), but mental existence or perspective is a lot more complex (post secondary), and being able to express that complexity more precisely, and therefore more clearly, is at the heart of this query.

Comment: Isn't the heart of this query an inability to express its complexity precisely, with clarity or simplicity… not the vocabulary you might need to invent to overcome tha?

I’ve worked with counsellors, so I know your 'we…' might speak for some; never for al1. Does that work for you? 

D'you say 'when I say "we," I mean helping the people we counsel distinguish between those mental perspectives' works in English?

D'you say I failed to grasp people conflating how they feel now about the past or future with what they felt in the past, or might in future?

Please think three times…

More…

Comment: Further… Think three times how 'what they felt in the past, or might feel in future…' might be re-written 'what they felt then, or might then', then take one step back…

Does 'what they felt then, or might in future' or 'what they felt in the past, or might then' fail?

Physical existence is not past, present or future, even to most stuck at primary school.

Barring specific artefacts, are dinosaurs or cave men, Greeks or Romans, now 'physical'? 

Isn't mental existence or perspective more complicated by trying to introduce special language, even if the new terms are explained well?